# Drawing simple 90degrees triangle in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

we started to learn javafx 3d and using TriangleMesh.
i am trying to draw a simple right(90 degree) triangle.(0,0),(0,50),(50,0)
whats wrong with my code?please

```
public class TT extends Application{



public void start(Stage primaryStage){
            TriangleMesh sqMesh=new TriangleMesh();

            sqMesh.getPoints().addAll(
                0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  //1top
                0.0f,50.0f,0.0f,  //1left
                50.0f,0.0f,0.0f  //1right

            );

            sqMesh.getTexCoords().addAll(
                    0,0
                    );
            sqMesh.getFaces().addAll(
                0,0, 1,0, 2,0

            );

            Group group=new Group();
            MeshView sq=new MeshView();
            sq.setMesh(sqMesh);
            sq.setTranslateX(200);
            sq.setTranslateY(100);
            sq.setTranslateZ(0);
            group.getChildren().add(sq);
            StackPane root=new StackPane();
            Scene scene=new Scene(root,900,600);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't add anything too the root StackPane. This is supposed to solve your problem.

```
root.getChildren().addAll(group);
```

However, the window size is very large relatively to the triangle, so I suggest to set the window size automatically to what in the window by creating the scene in the following way (without the size parameters):

```
Scene scene=new Scene(root);
```

And because the triangle's color is very similar to the background color, I also suggest you change the triangle's color to something more significant, like that:

```
sq.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLACK));
```

Comment: Thank you:-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Sorry it still doesnt paint the triangle.

Comment: @demianr Did you check your imports? From my experiences, it's very easy to accidentally import the Color package of another GUI library.

Comment: @demianr great, but a couple of tips for Stack Overflow: describe your errors with more details (in this case I could have guesses it was a wrong automatic import, but if you could've pasted the error message and the responder will know for sure), and upvote helpful answers.